# How to record failed ssh and email logins (usernames and passwords?)

Tags: ssh, postfix, dovecot, login, failed

I have a Debian VPS and I get a bunch of failed ssh/email (postfix, dovecot) login failures. In the logs I can see the username, but not the password. Is there a way to monitor both?

Log examples:

```
auth: Info: passwd-file(f_azmi@example.com,xx.xxx.xxx.xxx): unknown user
postfix/smtpd[16630]: warning: unknown[xx.xxx.xxx.x]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
spamc[15825]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
```

Comment: There are two things I am trying to achieve. First is to record and map all the forced attempts to hack/login into my server (yes, fail2ban is configured to ban them) - I want to write about the common usernames and passwords used in this type of attacks. 

Second, I want to see what is the most common missed login I do myself overtime. (I am the only one who has access). This would tell me what may be the strengths and weaknesses of my passwords.